Average subset of sorted filtered values
I have the following set of values:



col1
Col2




1
20


2
155


3
170


4
177


5
291


6
559


7
794


8
820


9
1,198


10
1,240


11
1,259


12
1,537


13
1,613


14
1,876


15
1,949


16
1,950


17
2,274


18
2,372


19
2,640


20
3,030


21
3,126


22
3,318


23
3,656


24
4,250


25
4,256


26
4,469


27
6,414


28
10,504


29
10,928


30
11,445


31
16,216



The second column's values were generated using:
=sort(FILTER(paste!M2:M, paste!$A$2:$A = A2, paste!$B$2:$B = B2, paste!$C$2:$C = C2, paste!$F$2:$F > 0))

I would like to do 3 calculations in 3 separate cells. I basically want to calculate the averages of 3 groups, but I'm not dividing the groups up evenly. I'm dividing these 3 groups by taking the number of total entries, in this case 31, and using this formula:
=QUOTIENT(AH2, 3)

where AH2 =31. In this case, that results in 10. So I want to find the average of the first 10 and the last 10 values, as well as the middle group.
For the middle group I'm using the formula
=QUOTIENT(count(B1:B31, 3) + MOD(countB1:B31, 3)

which equals 11. So I want the average of the middle 11 values.
So, my question is:
Is it possible in Google Sheets to find the average of a subset of sorted and filtered values, where one can specify the start and end of the subset using the nth number in the sequence? In this case, I want to find:

Group 1: the average of the smallest 10 values**

Group 2: the average of the 11th smallest through 21st smallest

Group 3: the average of the 22nd smallest through 31st smallest (largest)


I'm wanting formulas as references and not absolute numbers (1-10,11-21,22-31) that would split the groups by counting the total number of non blank entries and splitting it into 3 like this:
=QUOTIENT(count(B1:B31), 3)

for group 1 and 3 and then
=QUOTIENT(count(B1:B31, 3) + MOD(countB1:B31, 3)

for the middle group. I used subtotal in a separate part of
=SUBTOTAL(101,paste!I$2:I)

but I don't think I can use that with an ascending/sorted sequence for a portion of the data.

What if the count is 35? Or the count is 44? What will be the logic then to divide the count?

Try this formula in cell E2:
=transpose(
   map(
   {1,
    G2+1,
    query({B1:B},"select count(Col1) where Col1 is not null label count(Col1) ''")-(G2-1)
   },
   {G2,
    (G2*2)+(J16-(G2*3)),
    query({B1:B},"select count(Col1) where Col1 is not null label count(Col1) ''")
   },
   lambda(s,e,average(INDIRECT("B"&s&":B"&e))))
)


Logic

the formula is dynamic.

number of rows in the first and third sections is always = the quotient value
number of rows in the second section is always the quotient PLUS the difference between the count and (the quotient x 3).


map contains two arrays

the first is the first row in each range to be averaged
the second is the last row in each range to be averaged
the values are a multiple of the quotient +/- the difference between the count less (the quotient x 3).


lambda calculates the average for each range
the whole formula is transposed in order to display results in a column (this is optional, depending on how the OP proposes to display the results.


In the sample shown below:

the averages shown in Column C are calculated manually.
Cell G2 contains a formula: =QUOTIENT(query({B1:B},"select count(Col1) where Col1 is not null label count(Col1) ''"), 3)


SAMPLE


We CHOOSEROWS with indexes created by SEQUENCE for each batch. The correct sequence for each batch is calculated mathematically. Finally, we STACK the resulting ranges Horizontally and calculate the AVERAGE, BY each COL.
=LET(
    arr, A2:A,
    total, COUNT(arr),
    batch, QUOTIENT(total,3),
    lastBatch, total-batch,
    getBatch, LAMBDA(st, num, CHOOSEROWS(B2:B,SEQUENCE(num,1,st))),
    batches, HSTACK(getBatch(1,batch), getBatch(batch+1,lastBatch-batch), getBatch(lastBatch+1,batch)),
    BYCOL(batches, LAMBDA(c,AVERAGE(IFNA(c))))
)


How to split the data into three groups.
Try this approach.
I used the first Average Small to calculate the average of the smallest values and the same with the middle group.
The MOD(COUNTA(B1:B31), 3) calculates the remainder when the count of entries is divided by 3.It helps adjust the starting point for the middle group.
for the third group Average large getting the largest values from the data range. Similar with Small, but it retrieves the largest values instead.
for TOCOL Takes the array of averages by the ARRAYFORMULA and converts it into a single column format.
=TOCOL(ARRAYFORMULA({
    AVERAGE(SMALL(B1:B31, SEQUENCE(QUOTIENT(COUNTA(B1:B31), 3), 1, 1, 1))),
    AVERAGE(SMALL(B1:B31, SEQUENCE(QUOTIENT(COUNTA(B1:B31), 3) + MOD(COUNTA(B1:B31), 3), 1, QUOTIENT(COUNTA(B1:B31), 3) + 1, 1))),
    AVERAGE(LARGE(B1:B31, SEQUENCE(QUOTIENT(COUNTA(B1:B31), 3), 1, 1, 1)))
}))

Sample output

Reference

Small
Large
CountA
Average

Note: Please review the result to confirm if it meets your expectations. If not, kindly provide your expected result so I can adjust my response accordingly.
